# Error inserting a list item to Sharepoint using WSS via BizTalk "Cannot complete this action"

Tags: sharepoint, biztalk, biztalk-2013

I am getting this error when attempting to insert an item into a SharePoint list from BizTalk:

> The adapter failed to transmit message going to send port "SharepointTestResultUpload"            with URL "wss://localhost:13561/semiworks/Lists/TestResult". It will be retransmitted after the retry interval specified for this Send Port. Details:"[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException] Cannot complete this action.
>
> Please try again. Server Error Code: -2147467259Trace:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponseStream(Stream responseStream)
>       at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponse()
>        at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ExecuteQueryToServer(ChunkStringBuilder sb)
>        at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ExecuteQuery()
>        at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRuntimeContext.ExecuteQuery()
>        at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()
>        at Microsoft.BizTalk.KwTpm.WssAdapter.ClientOmAccessor.RequestInfo.get_Lists()
>        at Microsoft.BizTalk.KwTpm.WssAdapter.ClientOmAccessor.WebBucket.PopulateLists(RequestInfo reqInfo)
>        at Microsoft.BizTalk.KwTpm.WssAdapter.ClientOmAccessor.WebBucket.SafePopulateLists(RequestInfo reqInfo)
>        at Microsoft.BizTalk.KwTpm.WssAdapter.ClientOmAccessor.WebBucket..ctor(RequestInfo reqInfo)
>        at Microsoft.BizTalk.KwTpm.WssAdapter.ClientOmAccessor.ListsAccessor.GetWebBucket()
>        at Microsoft.BizTalk.KwTpm.WssAdapter.ClientOmAccessor.ListsAccessor..ctor(String siteUrl, String sharePointOnlineUsername, String sharePointOnlinePassword)
>        at Microsoft.BizTalk.KwTpm.WssAdapter.ClientOmAccessor.ListsAccessor.TryOpenWebSite(String siteUrl, String sharePointOnlineUsername, String sharePointOnlinePassword, Exception& lastError)
>
> This error was triggered by the Windows SharePoint Services receive location or send port with URI wss://localhost:13561/semiworks/Lists/TestResult.
>
> Windows SharePoint Services adapter event ID: 12310".

I am running BizTalk 2013 and SharePoint 2010 on the same server and the BizTalk server configuration shows the SharePoint Adapter as successfully installed/configured.

**EDIT**
I dug through the SharePoint logs and found the corresponding entry there:
http://pastebin.com/m2BaqViE
I already trimmed it down, but it is still long.
>

Answer (score 0):

I think the key error in SharePoint is "Failed to find the default form for PAGETYPE PAGE_EDITFORM" and this answer here
[Why won't the new item form create for an external list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/19248/why-wont-the-new-item-form-create-for-an-external-list) which advices to "delete the external list and recreate it" although it this case the person actually had to go as far as to create it with a new name before their problem was resolved.

Comment: I haven't deleted and recreated the list yet.  But I did create a brand new list and changed my BizTalk send port to target it and it still generated the same error.